# Using jQuery's Ajax handler with a form submitted by checkbox 'onchanged' event

Tags: jquery

I'm try to convert a form submission to jQuery's Ajax. The page holds a table - each row has a form with a checkbox where the onchanged property is submitting the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
```

Since I want to funnel any of the forms thru jQuery's Ajax handler I'm using a pattern i've seen plenty of examples use:

```
        $("form").live('submit', function (event) {
            alert("hit ajax");
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#myContainer").html(data);
                },
            });
        });
```

However, the code block above never executes - the form submits in the same fashion as before. Firebug doesn't report any errors - other jQuery functions on the page are working.

thx

Answer (score 1):

Put the event listener in JQuery too:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('#myCheckbox').change(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Also, IE won't play nice with that trailing comma in your example:

```
        success: function (data) {
            $("#myContainer").html(data);
        }, // <-- This guy
```

Comment: Makes sense - Except that I'm working with 'non-ID-able' checkboxes. Multiple rows in a table - each row with a form/checkbox. So whichever checkbox changes needs to pass someway to pass it's parent form.

Comment: `$(':checkbox').change({function(){$(this).parent('form').submit();});`

Answer (score 0):

Instead use:

```
$("form input:checkbox").live('click', function (event) {
```

(overrides click handlers of all checkboxes on page) and add this to the bottom of the original code block:

```
this.form.submit();
```